# Email delivery provider for Stack Exchange family of websites

Tags: discussion, email

I was wondering if Stack Exchange family of websites use an email delivery provider or they're sending emails directly from their own servers?

Answer (score 3):

They may, but it's hard for me to tell.

```
$ dig txt stackexchange.com +short
"v=spf1 a mx ip4:198.252.206.0/24 ip4:69.59.197.0/26 include:cmail1.com include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

Cmail1, as near as I can figure, provides services such as bulk email.

An email notification I recently received contained the following in the header:

```
X-Originating-IP: [198.252.206.125]
```

But using `dig` I see:

```
$ dig -x 198.252.206.125 +short
mx-out.stackexchange.com.
```

192.252.206.125 is covered in the SPF record by `ip4:198.252.206.0/24`.

Using `whois` on 198.252.206.125

```
$ whois 198.252.206.125
NetRange:       198.252.206.0 - 198.252.206.255
CIDR:           198.252.206.0/24
NetName:        SE-NET01
NetHandle:      NET-198-252-206-0-1
Parent:         NET198 (NET-198-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        Direct Assignment
OriginAS:       AS25791
Organization:   Stack Exchange, Inc. (SE-111)
RegDate:        2012-10-17
Updated:        2012-10-17
Comment:        http://stackexchange.com
Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-198-252-206-0-1

OrgName:        Stack Exchange, Inc.
OrgId:          SE-111
Address:        110 William St.
Address:        Floor 28
City:           New York
StateProv:      NY
PostalCode:     10038
Country:        US
RegDate:        2012-09-14
Updated:        2014-09-16
Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/org/SE-111

OrgTechHandle: SYSAD101-ARIN
OrgTechName:   Sysadmin Team
OrgTechPhone:  +1-212-232-8280
OrgTechEmail:  sysadmin-team@stackexchange.com
OrgTechRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/SYSAD101-ARIN

OrgAbuseHandle: SYSAD101-ARIN
OrgAbuseName:   Sysadmin Team
OrgAbusePhone:  +1-212-232-8280
OrgAbuseEmail:  sysadmin-team@stackexchange.com
OrgAbuseRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/SYSAD101-ARIN
```

I don't know enough about managing email for large sites, but it appears that perhaps Stack Exchange uses their own servers but have something additional setup for overflow on notification or other email functions.